# Django - Having trouble using foreign key model

Tags: python, sql, django, web-applications

**TL;DR Accessing an objects foreign key, *invoice must have one customer*, how can I show an invoice and it's customer data in HTML Template?**

I'm making an invoicing system, so I have these models.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, default='')
    phone_num = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class Invoice(models.Model):
    amount = models.FloatField(max_length=10, default=0)
    job_description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    date_of_issue = models.DateField(default='')
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.PROTECT, 
related_name='cus')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.job_description + "\t$" + str(self.amount))
```

**An Invoice has ONE and ONLY ONE Customer.**

I can easily print customers and invoices separately using templates. How can I access the customer which an invoice was sent to?

If I want to look up an invoice, how can I get the customers name and contact details to show in a template?

Currently I have displayed all of my invoices (looping through) and would like to show the customer name and ID number with the invoice information.

How can I then do it backwards and search for all invoices belonging to customer 'x'?

Comment: `An Invoice has ONE and ONLY ONE Customer.` then you should use `OneToOneField`.

Comment: @SachinKukreja Yep, thanks, I'm new to Django can ya tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ForeignKey in Django are many to one key . If your invoice has only one customer you use should use OneToOneKey instead.But anyways you can access it.

```
for invoice in Invoice.objects.all():
    invoice.customer # to get the model 
    invoice.customer.name # to get the name field of Customer model
```

in Template

```
{% for invoice in invoices %}
  {{ invoice.customer.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Request

```
return render(request, 'template_name.html',context={'invoices':Invoice.objects.all()})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
for inv in Invoice.objects.all():
    print(inv.custom.name)
    print(inv.custom.email)
```

In template:

```
{% for inv in invoices %}
      {{ inv.customer.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

And you need to send this information via context like:

```
return render(request, 'template.html', { 'invoices': Invoice.objects.all() })
```

You need to send the queryset from View to Template. You can use [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-render) to do that.

If you are using a Class Based View, then try like this:

```
class SomeListView(ListView):
    model = Invoice
    template = 'your_template.html'


# template for list view
{% for inv in object_list %}
    {{ inv.customer.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

See here for more details in [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview)

Comment: Not using class based view, just the first view I came across in the documentation ha! Your other stuff worked but I approve @Vivek Signh's answer cause he said OneToOneField.